# Unable to use variable in angularjs ng-include

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

i build a list using .factory and in every elemt have a arrtibute which store page which needed to be include when clicked on any list item
.
i am unable to use this attribute dynamiclly ..plzz help,,,,
i am using ionic framework

```js
////////////// service.js ////////////////





angular.module('starter.services', [])

.factory('Ctopic', function() {
  // Might use a resource here that returns a JSON array

  // Some fake testing data
  var chats = [ { title: 'Arrays', id:11 ,desc: "'ctopic/Union.html'"},
    { title: 'Bit Field Declaration', id:12 },
    { title: 'C Pointers', id: 13 },
    { title: 'Conditional Statements', id: 14 },
    { title: 'File IO', id: 15 },
    { title: 'Function', id: 16 },
    { title: 'Input & Output', id: 17 },
    { title: 'Loops', id: 18 },
    { title: 'Preprocessor Operators', id: 19 },
    { title: 'Preprocessor', id: 20 },
    { title: 'String', id: 21 },
    { title: 'Structures', id: 22 },
    { title: 'Typedef', id: 23 },
    { title: 'Union', id: 24 }];

  return {
    all: function() {
      return chats;
    },
    remove: function(chat) {
      chats.splice(chats.indexOf(chat), 1);
    },
    get: function(chatId) {
      for (var i = 0; i < chats.length; i++) {
        if (chats[i].id === parseInt(chatId)) {
          return chats[i];
        }
      }
      return null;
    }
  };
});
```

```html
///////   html page   /////////

<ion-view view-title="{{chat.title}}">
  <ion-content class="padding">
  {{chat.id}}
  {{chat.desc}}
    <div ng-include="{{chat.desc}}"></div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the brackets for `ng-include`:

```
<div ng-include="chat.desc"></div>
```

Comment: onther problem came up  if its not much to ask ...plz help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28982115/how-to-make-ng-repeat-list-items-link-to-a-html-page